# AttributeError("'str' object has no attribute 'cursor'",)

Tags: python, sqlite, bottle

So, I'm getting an this error when I start my bottle program. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpQdW.png I have no idea about how to fix this. I have looked up guides and tutorials for bottle-sqlite but there isn't much resources that can help me fix this problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
def positions_list(db, limit=10):
    cur = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT id, timestamp, owner, title, location, company, description FROM positions ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT "+str(limit)+""
    cur.execute(sql)
    return cur.fetchall()
```

Edit: I'm actually trying to past unittests. When I add:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('my_db')
```

The 500 error goes away but I fail my unittests. When I get the 500 error, I pass all my unittests. The main problem is that when test_position_add executes, it adds a new row and then screws up the rest of the test. Test here: https://pastebin.com/kLStWEAF

```
Expected :Job51
Actual   :Job50
```

I'm not sure if this is even relevant to my question but is affecting the unittests. I hope you can understand this mess, I can't explain it well and am new to this.

Comment: Can you show `db` argument?

Comment: can you post also the call to that function? Is seems you are passing a string

Comment: Hey Ryan, the error seems to be caused in the line `cur = db.cursor()`—it's saying that `db` does not have something caller `cursor` inside it. `db` should be a database connection, but it seems you're calling the function with a string. Can you include the place that you're calling this function from, and what values you're calling the function with?

Comment: I've added more information, hope it helps more.

Comment: @nrdsss_ how do you create object in your test? What is the type of `self.db`?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/C4t4l4J.png

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are passing a string as `db`.

Try this (I assume you are using sqlite3):

```
db = sqlite3.connect("your_db") # not db = "your_db"
resultset = employee_list(db)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this prior to your answer but it has led me to fail my unittests. I've added more information to the post and I hope it helps more to understand my problem.

Comment: Probably you do have problems in your unit tests (which class are you testing?). You cannot definitely call a cursors method on a string.